# How do I automatically calculate the values of a sine wave for a given number of positions?

Tags: c#, math

I have a minimum of 12 positions.  The min and max values are 0 and 1.  Hence if I want to draw a sinewave across my 12 positions (i.e. one value for each position) I would have a list of values like this: 0.5, 0.66, 0.83, 1, 0.83, 0.66, 0.5, 0.33. 0.16, 0, 0.16, 0.33, 0.5

But what if I wanted to expand the number of poisitons to 24, or 48, or 96, etc.  How would I work out the values (i.e. some algorithm rather than doing it by hand) ?

Note that my sinewave is not a repeating sinewave, just a single figure as constructed by the list above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sine wave equation is y = sin x (for the "unit" sine wave).

What you need to do is divide your x axis into the number of positions that you want to display, then display those x values.

Since your x max is 1, use:
**NOTE: Since a sine wave doesn't end at 1 on the x-axis, I am assuming that you want it to be bound to those values, as such the x-axis will be scaled so that 1.0 = 2*Pi**

```
double xStep = 1.0/NumberOfPositions;
```

then do:

```
for(double x = 0.0; x < 1.0; x += xStep)
{
    double yValue = Math.Sin(x*2*Math.PI); // Since you want 2*PI to be at 1
}
```

OR:

```
double xStep = 1.0/NumberOfPositions;
double[] yValues = new double[NumberOfPositions+1];
double[] xValues = new double[NumberOfPositions+1];
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPositions+1; i++)
{
    xValues[i] = i * xStep;
    yValues[i] = Math.Sin(xValues[i]*2*Math.PI); // Since you want 2*PI to be @ 1
}
```